# How to use CD command in Windows Terminal with custom environment variables?

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, environment-variables

If I create a environment variable, I can use it with Win+R and enter %MyVariable%. The directory opens in Windows Explorer.

However, if I try to do the following using Windows Terminal

```
cd %MyVariable%
```

or

```
cd "%MyVariable%"
```

it simply won't work.

Even trying with

```
cd %AppData%
```

won't work.
What should I do?

Comment: This lacks required info, as the above works in cmd. Your answer mentions PowerShell, a critical detail lacking, as PowerShell and cmd use two completely different characters for variables and neither recognizes the others _(cmd uses `%`, whereas PowerShell uses `$` and prefaces environment variables with `$env:<variable>`)_. e.g. **cmd:** `cd %AppData%` | **PowerShell:** `cd $env:AppData` - to use cmd variables in PowerShell, cmd must be called within the command by prefacing with `cmd /c`: `cmd /c cd %AppData%`

Answer (score 0):

By default, Windows Terminal opens Powershell, not Command Prompt.
You can change this in the settings.
[image]

Because Powershell is used, you will need `$env:MyVariable` to access the environmental variables.

To access the Settings, press the down arrow, then settings.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, now I understand that Windows Terminal is just PowerShell.

So, I have to use

```
cd %env:MyVariable.
```

Comment: "Windows Terminal is just PowerShell" it's not, I'd recommend checking the difference between a terminal and a shell.

Comment: Windows Terminal is a terminal which is something a shell (like cmd, powershell, bash, ksh, zsh...) attaches to. Obviously you can use any shells with Windows Terminal and there's also an option to set the default shell, although cmd is the worst out there

Comment: PowerShell does not use `%` for variables, it uses `$`